# Syntax Error: unexpected Token . when creating a recursive list

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function createList(arr) {
     if(!arr.length){
         return {value:arr[0], rest: null};                                                                        
     }
     else {
         return {
             value: arr[0] ,
             rest: {
                 createList(arr.slice(1))
             }
         };
     }
 }

 console.log(arrayToList([1,2,3]));
```

i'm working off chapter 4 from the eloquent javascript exercises and i can't seem to make this recursive list. It gives me a syntax error that the method "." call is a unexpected token

Comment: What's `arrayToList`?  I assume you meant to call `createList`.

Comment: Also why are you trying to access `arr[0]` after specifically checking to see if the length is 0?

Comment: I think the errors have already been pointed out, but if you give us the actual error output (including line numbers and stack trace, if available), we can help you a lot better.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rest: {
    createList(arr.slice(1))
}
```

This is being interpreted as an object, not a block statement.  It's looking for a `key: value` pair and it's not seeing that.

Try:

```
return {
    value: arr[0],
    rest: createList(arr.slice(1))
};
```